# Connect To MemSQL from C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, ado.net, singlestore

I'm new to MemSQL database, I've installed MemSQL database server on Linux Redhat V6.
I also Created a test database called "Test", the username is: root and password is: root
I can connect to this database locally, I also know that i can connect to MemSQL database from windows using MySQL provider for ODBC. I I tried to connect to MemSQL from Windows but i got an error (Connection Failed: Driver Lost Connection to MySQL Server at 'Reading Initial Communication Packet').
My Question is: Is it possible to Connect to MemSQL database from Windows or not? if yes, How can i do that using C# (What provider should i use, configurations,...etc).
Thank You

Answer (score 2):

That looks more like a network/firewall problem. Easiest way to check is to disable firewall on both client and server to see if everything works then.

MemSQL just uses MySQL compatibility so the official MySQL C# client will work fine. You can install it from nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/

```
PM> Install-Package MySql.Data
```

Here's a quick example in MemSQL documentation to test inserts:

http://docs.memsql.com/latest/concepts/multi_insert_examples/#c

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace MemSQLTest {
  //Thread creates a connection and inserts for 1000 milliseconds
  public class WorkerThread {
    public static void Thread() {
      try {
        IDbConnection conn;
        conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1;Uid=root;Pwd=;";
        conn.Open();

        IDbCommand dbcmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        dbcmd.CommandText = "USE db";
        dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dbcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO t VALUES (DEFAULT)";
        Stopwatch stop = new Stopwatch();
        stop.Start();
        while(stop.ElapsedMilliseconds < 1000)
        {
          dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
      } catch (Exception ex) {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      }
    }
  }
  class MemSQLTest {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      try {
        IDbConnection conn;
        conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1;Uid=root;Pwd=;";
        conn.Open();

        //Initialize database with auto increment table
        IDbCommand dbcmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        dbcmd.CommandText = "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS db";
        dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dbcmd.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE db";
        dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dbcmd.CommandText = "USE db";
        dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dbcmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE t (id int primary key auto_increment)";
        dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //Initialize threads
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[10];
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
          threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WorkerThread.Thread));
          threads[i].Start();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
          threads[i].Join();
        }
        //Show select count(*) on auto increment table
        dbcmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t";
        IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(reader.Read()) {
          Console.WriteLine(reader["COUNT(*)"]);
        }
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      }
    }
  }
}
```